# Nonexpansive Affine Operators in Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with real inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Let $T$ be an affine operator.

Show that $T$ is nonexpansive, i.e., $\left\| T(x) - T(y) \right\| \leq \left\| x-y\right\|$ for all $x,y \in H$, if and only if
$$ \langle T(x) - T(y), \ x-y\rangle \leq \left\| x-y\right\|^2.$$

Comments.

I started with finite-dimensional $H$: $T(x) = Ax+b$. So $\langle T(x) - T(y), \ x-y\rangle = (x-y)^\top A (x-y) \leq \left\| x-y\right\|^2$ if and only if $A \preccurlyeq I$. Hence $A \preccurlyeq I$ implies $T$ being nonexpansive. I am not sure about the other implication, that is, $T$ nonexpansive implies $A \preccurlyeq I$. Once the finite-dimensional case is proven, perhaps the general case has a similar proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact if $T$ is non-expansive then the proposed inequality follow from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, since with notation of the proposer we have
$$
\langle T(x)-T(y),x-y\rangle=
\langle A(x-y),x-y\rangle\leq\Vert A(x-y)\Vert\,\vert x-y\Vert\leq\Vert x-y\Vert^2.
$$

Now, the converse is not correct in general without supplementary assumptions, for instance, 
If $T(x)=-2x$ then the proposed inequality becomes trivial: $-3\Vert x-y\Vert^2\leq \Vert x-y\Vert^2$, while clearly $T$ is expansive.

A less trivial example is given on $\Bbb{R}^2$ by the matrix $A=\left[\matrix{0&5\cr-5&0}\right]$.

Comment: So shoult it be $A^\top A \preccurlyeq I$?

Comment: This is clearly a sufficient condition.